# Can I change font Color and/or Type for IDE 1.5.6r2?

Tags: arduino-ide

The program becomes harder to read (at least on my particular monitor) after upgrading.

Any way to change font **Color to darker** color and/or **Type to thicker stroke** (like B in this question editor) for IDE 1.5.6r2?

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a fully theme-able IDE.  Why not give [UECIDE](http://uecide.org) a go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Under the file menu select the preferences. From this you can find and than view/edit the preferences.txt file, which has the color settings.

Example [preferences.txt](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/lib/preferences.txt)

Comment: I log on as Admin (Win7) but cannot save the edit due to "access deny". Checked the property and 'ticked' for read, write and full control.

Comment: Solved. The one to change is C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Arduino15\preferences.txt

Comment: In 1.6.0, or 1.6.1 it does not seem to be possible to change `console.color` or `console.error.color`. To be precise, you can change the settings in the preferences.txt file, but they appear to be ignored. Have these become hard coded? Orange text on black is just horrific to read. See [How do I change the Console colour of Arduino IDE?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/how-do-i-change-the-console-colour-of-arduino-ide)

Comment: The link is broken (Google Code was shut down).

Comment: What about the thicker stroke? What should e.g. `editor.font=Monospaced,plain,16` be replaced with (supposedly `plain` with something else)?