# How do I change the Console colour of Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide

Leading on from the question [Can I change font Color and/or Type for IDE 1.5.6r2?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4364/can-i-change-font-color-and-or-type-for-ide-1-5-6r2), in 1.6.0, or 1.6.1<sup>1</sup> it does not seem to be possible to change `console.color` or `console.error.color`. To be precise, you can change the settings in the `preferences.txt`<sup>2</sup> file, but they appear to be ignored when the IDE is restarted. Have these become hard coded?  I see from the [preference.txt example file](https://code.google.com/p/arduino/source/browse/trunk/build/shared/lib/preferences.txt?r=71) that

```
# Some colors have been hardcoded into the source in app/ in order to ensure
# consistency with the images distributed and stored with the application.
# They have been commented out below so that users who install an old
# version of the software will not get incorrect colors left-over from this
# config file.
```

However, the settings to which I refer are not commented out, and so would led me to believe that they can be changed. Orange text on black is just horrific to read.

For example:

```
console.error.color=#FFF000
console.color=#FFCCCC
```

but I still get white/orange(red?) text for the output and error messages respectively.

I am making the edits while the Arduino IDE is not running.

---

<sup>1</sup> In 1.6.3 the ignored `console.color` etc. lines appear to have been removed from the `preferences.txt` file.

<sup>2</sup> `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Arduino15\preferences.txt`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that the `theme.txt` configuration file is *not* located alongside the `preferences.txt` file, but alongside/under the Arduino application's `.jar` files. Thus, for the current version (1.6.3):

- on OS X, `.../Arduino-1.6.3.app/Contents/Java/lib/theme/theme.txt`
- on Win7, `C:\Program Files\Arduino\lib\theme\theme.txt`
- on Linux, `.../arduino-1.6.3/lib/theme/theme.txt`
- on Windows 10, when installed as an App, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\lib\theme\theme.txt, however it does not seem possible to edit it - it can be opened in notepad++ but a save fails.

See an associated Github issue, [IDE Background and print color options needed](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/1878), for a little more discussion.

Comment: Thanks for that. BTW, the Windows path is `C:\Program Files\Arduino\lib\theme\theme.txt`.  It does beg the question why are the `console.error` and `console.color` lines in the `preferences.txt` file if they are ignored. The Arduino IDE truly is a shockingly terrible piece of software. However, having said that, I notice that in version 1.6.3 the lines appear to have been removed.

Comment: If you've put those lines in `preferences.txt` (as I did), then they'll still be there after the IDE has read and re-dumped the properties, even though the IDE ignores them. Myself, I don't much like the IDE editor, so I use an external editor (setting the appropriate preference), and just use the IDE to compile and upload – for that, for me, it works well enough. Anyone out there who can add the path to the theme file under Linux?

Comment: I've added the Windows and Linux paths to your answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Greenonline Looks great!

Answer (score 2):

Download the Dark Theme of Jeff Thompson from [Github: jeffThompson/DarkArduinoTheme](https://github.com/jeffThompson/DarkArduinoTheme)

[image: Jeff Thompson's - Dark Arduino Theme]

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Jeff Thompson's - Dark Arduino Theme]